# Can Pokemon caught on the Pokéwalker have their Hidden Abilities?

Tags: pokemon-heart-gold-soul-silver, pokemon-hgss-pokewalker

Is there a chance of catching a Pokemon with its hidden ability on the Pokéwalker? Is the ability random, restricted to just the normal abilities, or predefined?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, hidden abilities were added in Gen. 5, but Pokewalker is Gen. 4 only (specifically HG/SS), so every Pokemon you catch there has one of the normal abilities.